# What is the speed of a link aggregation having two interfaces of 1 Gbps each?

Tags: networking

What bandwidth can I expect to achieve from a link aggregation consisting of two 1 Gbps interfaces?

Answer (score 3):

A 1 Gbps interface can transfer 1 Gbps regardless of whether it is in a bundle or used by itself.

Each flow is assigned to a link chosen in a pseudo random way. In other words, for every one of your TCP connections the source and destination IP and port numbers are hashed in order to choose one of the links in the bundle.

This means no single TCP connection can use more than 1 Gbps. And if two TCP connections get assigned to the same interface they cannot use more than 1 Gbps combined.

But if you have enough individual TCP connections to get them evenly spread across the links in your bundle, then you can run 1 Gbps on every link in the bundle.

If both endpoints support MPTCP it is possible for a single TCP connection to utilize both links, but MPTCP is not widely supported.